# How to resolve undefined error in php

Tags: php

```
<?php

   $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hcis") or die(mysqli_error());
   $q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `vaccine` NATURAL JOIN `itr` WHERE `itr_no` = '$_GET[itr_no]' && `epi_id` = '$_GET[epi_id]'") or die(mysqli_error());
   $f = $q->fetch_array();

?>
```

This is my code. I am getting this error

> Notice: Undefined index: itr_no in C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis\admin\epi_print.php on line 25
>
> Notice: Undefined index: epi_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis\admin\epi_print.php on line 25

I tried googling it and found that I have to use **`isset`** but I do not know where to put the **`isset`**.

Comment: Read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2):

You query is vulnerable as you are passing url variables (user input directly) to database query.

Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) for checking whether the variable we are using is defined.

Corrected code should be:

```
$itr_no = isset($_GET['itr_no']) ? $_GET['itr_no'] : '';
$epi_id = isset($_GET['epi_id']) ? $_GET['epi_id'] : '';

$itr_no = $conn->real_escape_string($itr_no);
$epi_id = $conn->real_escape_string($epi_id);

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hcis") or die(mysqli_error());
$q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `vaccine` NATURAL JOIN `itr` WHERE `itr_no` = '$itr_no' && `epi_id` = '$epi_id'") or die(mysqli_error());
$f = $q->fetch_array();
```

Comment: This is a better solution as it separates the data source and allows you to perform some kind of validation before hitting the database code.

Comment: @TechieMickey, please debug through the code by printing what you are exactly getting from database and you will get the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> having this udefined error again and again

Because, you are trying to access index of an array, which is not defined. In your case, you are trying to access index `itr_no` and `epi_id` from array `$_GET`.

1. Verify your URL query string of request, if it contains or may be your form.

or

2. check if value `isset` before accessing it

   ```
   if(isset($_GET['itr_no']) && isset($_GET['epi_id'])){
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**Using [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check your $_GET request value**,

```
<?php

   $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hcis") or die(mysqli_error());

   //Checkes Whether itr_no And epi_id is available or not
   //runs when all are available
   if(isset($_GET['itr_no']) && isset($_GET['epi_id'])){
     $q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `vaccine` NATURAL JOIN `itr` WHERE `itr_no` = '$_GET[itr_no]' && `epi_id` = '$_GET[epi_id]'") or die(mysqli_error());
     $f = $q->fetch_array();
   }

?>
```

**Use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check $_GET request value**

```
<?php

   $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hcis") or die(mysqli_error());

   //Checkes Whether itr_no And epi_id is available or not
   //runs when all are available
   if(!empty($_GET['itr_no']) && !empty($_GET['epi_id'])){
     $q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `vaccine` NATURAL JOIN `itr` WHERE `itr_no` = '$_GET[itr_no]' && `epi_id` = '$_GET[epi_id]'") or die(mysqli_error());
     $f = $q->fetch_array();
   }

?>
```

If you don't want to check using if then at starting you should use to **check your $_GET request values like**,

```
$itr_no = isset($_GET['itr_no']) ? $_GET['itr_no'] : '';
$epi_id = isset($_GET['epi_id']) ? $_GET['epi_id'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` is used to check if the variable is set and is not `null`. Details: https://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php.

So you should use `isset()` before you access the `$variable`. For example:

```
if (isset($example['id']) {
    echo $example['id'];
}
```

The example above makes sure that if `$example['id']` is set, you can access it. If you don't have isset, the `echo` would run even if `$example['id']` was `null` or undefined - and that would throw an error.

@techiemickey: however, you error is caused by the reason that, you access var in the wrong way. You shout use **$_GET['itr_no']** instead of **$_GET[itr_no]**

Answer (score 0):

You need surround you form data like, `$GET['id']` 
Your edited code

```
<?php

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hcis") or die(mysqli_error());
    $q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `vaccine` NATURAL JOIN `itr` WHERE `itr_no` = '$_GET['itr_no']' && `epi_id` = '$_GET['epi_id']'");
    $f = $q->fetch_array();

  ?>
```